# Can you give me some advices to draw DFT graph in python with scipy

Tags: python

I'm sorry to ask you guys about this, 
but this is the first time I use python and FFT either..
I want to draw a graph like below with abnormal.py integer array, but web searching is not quite helpful so far.

So, just look through the contents and throw me some advice

(abnormal.npy contains an array of 3865 positive integer values and they stand for the number of some events each day)

**Below is the graph that I want to draw**

[image]

**Here is the code that I'm trying**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
import pylab as pl
import numpy.fft as fft

data = np.load('C:\\Users\\python\\Desktop\\abnormal.npy')
freq = fft.fftfreq(len(data))
power = np.abs(freq)**2

pl.figure()
pl.plot(freq, power)
pl.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
pl.ylabel('plower')
pl.show()
```